# How to schedule an Airflow DAG to run Bi-monthly

Tags: python, cron, airflow

I would like to run an Airflow DAG bi-monthly on a particular Wednesday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `0 0 1,15 * 3` to `schedule_interval`.

It is a cron expresssion which means **“At 00:00 on day-of-month 1 and 15 and on Wednesday.”**